# passing id on href and submitting form on same page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making social project form and im trying to add reply ..the reply button is a link that sends user to reply.php page with post id saved in href...on the reply.php my form action is the same page but when i click button to submit form it doesnot get the id and refreshes page with post and display error undefined id need help..

here is my reply.php

```
<?php
require('session.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
//echo $id;


  $submit=@$_POST['submit'];
      $reply=@$_POST['reply'];


      if(isset($submit)){
           $id=@$_GET['id'];
          $sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO REPLY (reply,Username,post_id) VALUES '$reply','$user_check','$id'");

          $sql2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM REPLY WHERE post_id= '$id'");
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
              echo $row['Username']."<br/>".$row['reply']."<br/>";



          }



      }
else "error in submission";
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Studhelp</title>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<?php
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from posts  where post_id='$id'");
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){?>
<!-- Middle Column -->
    <div class="w3-col m7">

      <div class="w3-row-padding">
        <div class="w3-col m12">
          <div class="w3-card-2 w3-round w3-white">
            <div class="w3-container w3-padding">
              <h3 class="w3-opacity"><?php echo $row['Username'] ;?></h3>
              <?php 

                  echo $row['Posts']."<br/>".$row['date']."<br/>";
              }
             ?>
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<form action="reply.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="reply" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="reply">


</form>
```

this is the anchor tag send id to reply.php

```
<a href="reply.php?id=<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>" class="reply-comment"> Reply </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you need to be able to read your "id" variable after you post the form. To achieve this use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET, like this:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

And also pass the variable with your form, as a hidden field:

```
<form action="reply.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<input type="text" name="reply" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="reply" />

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for help..the problem is solved i just have to mention in form action

 <form action="reply.php ?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

You didn't check if the fom was submitted

Enclose other PHP code after session.php inside a conditional checker such as:

if ($_POST):

You can use form tags to create a form and put the id field as hidden.

GET requests shouldn't be use to modify data